# How to detect an empty div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I can't use:

```
$('div:empty')
```

because the div might have empty spaces in it. I want to remove it if it has nothing or nothing but empty spaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will return all `div` elements with no text apart from blank spaces (or other characters removed by [`.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) such as new line characters):

```
var emptyDivs = $("div").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "";
});
```

**Update** - based on comments

If any of the `div` elements in question have child elements which do not contain text (for example, `img` elements) then the above method will include them in the set of "empty" elements. To exclude them, you can use the following:

```
var emptyDivs = $("div").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "" && $(this).children().length === 0;
});
```

Comment: Watch out, as if you have elements inside your div that don't have any text (like an image), it seem empty using this method. My answer takes care of this.
`$.trim($("<div>").append($("<img>").attr("src", "test")).text())`

Comment: Yes, that's true. If that's the case for the OP, a combination of our answers should do the trick nicely!

Comment: Seeing as your answer will be the first one seen by others looking for this, might you consider editing your post to mention that problem?

Comment: Already on it :) and +1 to your answer too. (I've made it check explicitly for the empty string and length 0, even though they would coerce to `false`, just for clarity).

Answer (score 7):

Based on @Xeon06's answer, you can extend jQuery's selectors to find all elements with no content:

```
$.expr[':'].nocontent = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
    // obj - is a current DOM element
    // index - the current loop index in stack
    // meta - meta data about your selector
    // stack - stack of all elements to loop

    // Return true to include current element
    // Return false to explude current element
    return !($.trim($(obj).text()).length) && !($(obj).children().length)
};
```

usage for you would then be:

```
$('div:nocontent').remove();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/JNZtt/

Answer (score 4):

You could use this condition:

```
if (!$.trim($("div").text()).length && !$("div").children().length)
```

The additional `children` length check is to make sure that you don't consider a div with no text but other elements (for example, images) as empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($.trim($('div').html()) == '') { $("div").remove(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('div:empty').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).html()).length == 0){
        //do what you want here...
    }
});
```